# Background colour change of Chrome icon

Tags: google-chrome

The background colour of the chrome icon is normally blue on my taskbar. But recently, I am noticing that the background colour becomes orange sometimes and stays that way for a while, before returning to blue after some time, on its own. I have started using Windows 10 a few months back. Would this have any connection with Windows 10 installation ?

Comment: If pictures were to be added, a whole new meaning would arise from this question. Therefore, please add a few pictures, so that we can understand the situation better.